# How to optimize website for Snap (multi-window mode in Windows)?

Tags: html, css, web

I was just wondering how I can better optimize my website (its just a project, not real) for Snap mode in Windows.  Whenever I go into that mode, it screws up the entire webpage (see attached photo).

Thanks Jacob

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4yF2.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href ="C:\Users\toshiba\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application\public_html\css\index.css">
         <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css" rel ="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> JP's Webservices</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id ="body">  
        <div class = "nav">
            <ul> 
                <li> 
                  <a href = "#"> About Me </a> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                  <a href = "#"> Contact Me </a> 
                </li>
                <li> 
                  <a href = "#"> Pricing </a> 
                </li> 
            </ul>


        </div>

        <div class ="jumbotron">

           <div class ='container'>
              <div id ='h1'>
                  <h1> Need a website? </h1>
                  <p> Look no further </p> 
              </div>


           </div>
        </div> 
          <div id ="white"> 
          <h1> Qualities </h1>
          <h3> What makes me unique? </h3> 
          </div> 
        <div id ="gray"> 

        </div> 
        <div  class ="des" >
          <div class ="row"> 
            <div class= "col-md-4">  
             <h2> Knowledge. </h2> 
                 <p> Straight 'outta Compton 1231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231 </p> 
             <hr> 
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-4"> 
             <h2> Commitment. </h2>
                 <p> To excellence and to serve as a value resource 123123123123123123123123123123123123 </p>  
             <hr> 
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-4"> 
             <h2> Perspective. </h2> 
                 <p> New outlook on your web designs 12312312312311111111111111111111111111111111111111111 </p> 
             <br> 
            </div> 
           </div> 
         </div>



    </body> 




    <footer>
        <div id ='footer'>

        </div>
        <div id ='footer1'>
           <p> Copyright @2014-2015  Jacob Platin </p> 
            <div id ='foot1'>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/TheJakeoShark"  target=newtab><img src="https://g.twimg.com/Twitter_logo_blue.png"  width="72" height="46" border="0" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id ='facebook'>
                <a href ='https://facebook.com/jacob.platin'  target=newtab><img src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/267px-F_icon.svg.png' width ="65" height =" 53" /></a> 
            </div>
        </div> 

    </footer>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.des {
    position: absolute; 

    font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    text-align: center; 


}

.nav li {

    list-style-type: none; 
    text-align: center; 
    float: left; 
    width: 33.3%; 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    color: black; 
    padding-top: 17px;
    font-weight: 700; 
    font-size: 18px; 


}
.nav {

    background-color: #660000; 
    height: 85px;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black; 
}
.nav a {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: black; 
    font-weight: 700; 
    color: white;
}




.jumbotron  {


   position:relative;
   background-image: url(http://www.welivesecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/012838004-printed-internet-html-code-tec.jpg);
   width: 100%;
   height: 530px;



}

#h1 > h1 {
    color:#660000;
    text-align:left ;
    padding-top: 34px;
    font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px black;
}
#h1 > p {
    color:white;
    text-align:left ;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px black;
    font-weight: 300;
}


#master_wrapper{overflow:hidden!important;}
#footer {

    width: 1902px;
    height: 170px; 
    background-color: black; 
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px 4px black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1300px;

}

#footer1 {

    height: 85px;
    width: 1902px;
    background-color: #660000; 
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    box-shadow: -4px -2px 9px black;
    top: 1300px;
}

#footer1 > p {
    text-align: center; 
    font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px; 
    padding-top: 24px; 

}

#foot1 {

    padding-top: 42px; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 205px;


}

#facebook {
    margin-left: 820px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    top: 95px;

}

.des > h2 {

    padding-top: 80px;
    color: #660000
}

#photo1 {

    background-image: url(http://financeandcareer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/webProgrammingInternship.jpg);
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;

}
.des > img {

    margin-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 01px 01px 01px 5px black;
}

#h1 {

    box-shadow: -1px -1px -32px black; 
}

#gray {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -11;
    margin-top: 0px;

}

#white > h1 {
    z-index: 1;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#660000;  
    text-align: center;

}

#white > h3 {
    font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#660000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 230px;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: 43.3%; 

}

.row {
    padding-left: 56px;
    z-index:-1;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to resizing the site via snapping (taking up 50%) of the screen width? If you want your site to work whatever the the screen width you need to use fluid containers and media queries, which make up the concept of responsive web design.

From the looks of things your site uses fixed widths which limit the ability for the content to re-size fluidly with the browser when you snap.

Responsive webdesign needs to be integrated form the get go, it can be annoying to update an existing site (but still possible). I'd recommend taking a look at this tutorial/overview: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

In short to fix your site you will need to get rid of the fixed widths you have set in pixels and uses percentages as they will adapt depending on the available width.